# How can I return the URL to my git repo after a git push?

Tags: git, github

I want to print the URL of my GitHub repo after I push my code into my remote branch. When I push a new branch to master, it actually behaves as I want it to

```
➜  MyProject git:(test) git pushup test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'test' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/DanielShterenberg/MyProject/pull/new/test
remote: 
To github.com:DanielShterenberg/MyProject.git
 * [new branch]      test -> test
Branch 'test' set up to track remote branch 'test' from 'origin'.
```

But then, when I'm executing `git push` with new changes into the same branch, I'm getting the following

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 301 bytes | 301.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To github.com:DanielShterenberg/MyProject.git
   commitID1..commitID2  test -> test
```

I tried reading about commit hooks and about the remote repo, but couldn't find the answer. Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want Git to just print `https://github.com/<org>/<project>/pull/new/<branch>`? That is, the URL to make a new PR in your project for that branch?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Schwern @Jeff Mercado for your answers. I used both of them and created the following `pre-push` script which can also be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DanielShterenberg/aebbd5d30ac5b74d5fc2ad0c239a2fac).

```
#!/bin/sh

remote=$1
url=$2

###extract host:
host=${url#*@} # chop off the beginning until the first '@'
host=${host%%:*} # chop off everything after the first ':'

###extract org:
org=${url#*:} # chop off the beginning until the first ':'
org=${org%%/*} # chop off everything after the first '/'

###extract project
project=${url#*/} # chop off the beginning until the first '/'
project=${project%%.*} # chop off the beginning until the first '.'
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha; do
    if [ $host='github.com' ]; then
        remote_branch=${remote_ref#*/*/} # get the part after the second '/'
        echo "https://github.com/${org}/${project}/pull/new/${remote_branch}\n"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any hooks defined for "post-push" but you could use `pre-push` instead.

Create a `pre-push` hook to echo the url. The url is the second argument of the hook. The name of the remote is the first.

```
#!/bin/sh

remote=$1
url=$2

echo $url

exit 0
```

Though note this just prints the url of the remote repo, what you seem to be looking for is a url to create a new pull request. Just generate the appropriate url instead. You'll have to read stdin to get the refs that are being pushed. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

remote=$1
url=$2

# assuming git urls
org=${url:git@github.com:}
org=${org%/*}
project=${url:git@github.com:*/}
project=${project%.git}

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha; do
    if [ "$remote_sha" = "$z40" ]; then
        # new branch
        remote_branch=${remote_ref#refs/remotes/${remote}/}
        echo "https://github.com/${org}/${project}/pull/new/${remote_branch}"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: "Though note this just prints the url of the remote repo" - in my case it does not print the URL to the remote repo, but actually prints this `github.com:DanielShterenberg/MyProject.git`

Comment: Well, it's a URL... just a git URL apparently.

Comment: I agree:)
This is the one I'm trying to change into a regular HTTP URL.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to print the URL for a new PR using that branch, write a `pre-push` hook. `.git/hooks/pre-push.sample` shows what arguments it takes.

```
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>
```

For you that would look like...

- $1 = origin
- $2 = git@github.com:DanielShterenberg/MyProject.git

  - Or https://github.com/DanielShterenberg/MyProject.git

You'd need to parse the host, org, and project from the URL. Then get the remote branch from the first line of stdin.

Here's some pseudo-code to get you started.

```
remote=ARGV[0]
url=ARGV[1]

host, org, project = parse_url(url)

if host == 'github.com'
  local_ref, local_commit, remote_ref, remote_commit = parse_line(stdin)

  # remote_ref will be like refs/heads/branch, you want just branch.
  remote_branch = ref2branch(remote_ref)
  print "https://github.com/#{org}/#{project}/pull/new/#{remote_branch}\n"
end
```